# Can i use tomcat ajp connector without using fronted tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, ajp

I am creating some standalone web application with java spring using a tomcat web server in a container. Can some one give me a example to use a ajp conncetor? My further destination is to connect my web-application with tls. Maybe you have some idea to make a https connecting within a tomcat container?

Thank you alot, Mira